# Spatial query of OpenStreetMap data - do I need a big data approach?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, openstreetmap, postgis, distributed-computing

I'm looking to execute spatial queries on the OpenStreetMap dataset.  Specifically, I have a polygon grid with dimensions of 0.001 degree covering the globe and I'd like to select all the grid cells that meet various criteria (e.g. contains a major road). With Postgres/PostGIS alone, this is fairly straightforward; but given the number of grid cells I would be querying, I'm assuming that is a pretty time consuming operation.  Thus I am looking for a distributed computing option.

A bit of research leads me to an article demonstrating the loading of the [OpenStreetMap dataset into Parquet and then querying that data with Apache Spark SQL](http://blog.improve-osm.org/en/2017/11/is-openstreetmap-big-data-ready/). The queries demonstrated are not spatial, and I assume spatial queries are not supported by Apache Spark.

GeoSpark seems to be one option, though its native inputs don't include pbf format.  Are there transformations to get OpenStreetMap pbf files, GeoSpark-ready?

Are there other options for such an operation with a distributed system?

Comment: This does lead itself nicely to a divide & conquer strategy that systems like hadoop are well suited for. However, you should also be able to this iteratively in pgis as well. Perhaps using a "mipmap" (decreasing LOD) style of increasing grid size "filter" geometries to remove negative matches before drilling down to the closest level.